# ./configure: What is an insane build environment?

Tags: compiling, configure

`./configure` always checks `whether the build environment is sane...`

I can't help but wonder what exactly a insane build environment is. What errors can this check raise?

Comment: http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/371:_Compiler_Complaint

Comment: You may check `config.log` for what actual commands are run there or programs compiled.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This comes from [automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/), specifically from its `AM_SANITY_CHECK` [macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Private-Macros), which is called from [`AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Public-Macros), which is normally called early in `configure.ac`. The gist of this macro is:

- Check that the path to the source directory doesn't contain certain “unsafe” characters which can be hard to properly include in shell scripts makefiles.
- Check that `ls` appears to work.
- Check that a new file created in the build directory is newer than the `configure` file. If it isn't (typically because the clock on the build system is not set correctly), the build process is likely to fail because build processes usually rely on generated files having a more recent timestamp than the source files they are generated from.

Comment: Why `ls` specifically? Is it only to test that basic executables are available and functional or is `ls` itself somehow used in the make process?

Comment: @terdon Some automake templates use `ls`. The `AM_SANITY_CHECK` macro itself uses `ls` to check the relative times of `configure` and a temporary file (it doesn't use `test -nt` because not all shells have it).